# Secure data transfer (for DB/ETL)

Tags: database, data

Does anyone know of any tool, ETL suite or BI suite that enables safe and secure data transfer from one location to another, over internet to an offsite database in the cloud? Or, what approaches could be deployed for this, if no off the shelve product exists for this? Preferably database-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Talend would be a good ETL tool for secure data integration from basically any data source to the cloud.

One thing to consider is if you will also need Data Quality, Master Data Management, and/or Data Governance capabilities.

The Gartner Magic Quadrant indicates Talend is a leader for both Data Integration and Data Quality. Forrester Wave indicates Talend as a Data Fabric leader.

FYI, I work for Talend.  =)

Comment: thanks for your disclaimer, that's appreciated here. I've personally never worked with Talend before, but I keep hearing about it. A quick look on the website didn't help me further (seems that the bigger the company, the harder it is to find info on their technical features). Can you point me to a whitepaper or something on the Talend site that explains how Talend connects to offsite data sources?

Comment: for my project getting data safely and smoothly from A to B is actually the biggest challenge. DQ, MDM, DG are, at this point, not really an issue yet.

Comment: How depends upon the data source. Talend utilizes native interfacing on most connectors. You can find a list of many of the connectors on this page, https://www.talend.com/connectors/. For more specifics on a certain connector, I would go to the manual at https://help.talend.com/. If you like getting hands on to see how the connects work, then you can grab a trial at https://www.talend.com/download/. Back to the security aspect, a good white paper is available at https://www.talend.com/resources/integrate-data-securely-cloud/. Hope that helps.